# Use the same array in multiple PHP pages

Tags: php

In one PHP page I collect some data on the server (i.e. a list of the file in a folder) and show it into a table. The user may require to delete one file. Because I'm new to PHP I don't know if my approach is correct. Let's see some code:

### list.php

```
<?php
$path = "/path/to/directory/";
$files = array_diff(scandir($path), array('.', '..'));
?>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i++) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="d-none"><?php echo "{$i}"?></td>
        <td><?php echo "{$files[$i]}"?></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm delete"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>
        </td>                                                               
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

### index.js

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(e) {
    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(0).html();
    var filename = $(this).closest("tr").find('td').eq(1).html();

    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php?id=" + id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
});
```

### delete.php

```
$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
parse_str($query, $params); 
$id = $params["id"]; 
$path = "/path/to/directory/";
//$filename = ???;
//unlink($path . $filename);
echo "success";
```

Some options I thought:

1. Instead of the `id` pass the `filename` as parameter of the `DELETE` query. I guess it's not a good way.
2. list.php should place the file names into a db, so I can access them everywhere. Actually I did it, on a "live" db in `/dev/shm` but I wonder if it's a valid approach. Every time the page reloads I need to drop the table and create it again (on the page there's a refresh button for this purpose)
3. use the `$_SESSION` variable to store the array so the `delete.php` page can retrieve the `filename` by its `id`.

*Please note, I'm not asking for an opinion about the three options. I'm asking what is the right approach from a technical point of view: safety, performances, reliability, etc...*

Comment: Very broad to answer on also still this would be a primarily opinion-based question..

Comment: .. also whats is the point of the system? is it required a trusted person (by trusted authentication) to possible delete files in a directory?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes, it's a development machine and there's one specific directory where users can load and remove files (using the web app). For this reason the path is hard-coded: they can only choose the filename, not the path.

Comment: Well the safety is as strong as the weakest link, so if the authentication method/layer is leak the whole system after is also simply unsafe..   Also consider reasking this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/  or https://security.stackexchange.com as this question is more or less in the gray area of been considerd [offtopic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here... Also be ready to post  more of your code  when asked for then poeple can give much more solid advice instead of guessing..

Comment: Speaking of trusted authentication -> There is a new web standard which is called  [Web Authentication](https://w3c.github.io/webauthn/) .. also better explained on [Guide to Web Authentication](https://webauthn.guide/) ... it's a javascript API which can use windows hello/usb token for example to register/login on you in on a webapplication..   The link explains how it works on the browser side and in some detail in minimal what a webapplication should do to keep it safe.  Browser support are the modern Edge, Firefox and Chrome browsers versions... But i think there already might be PHP libs

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 is okay, If you just want a fast and easy internal solution. But making the filename visible can lead to security vulnerabilties. (See comments below)

Option 2 is much slower and DB and filesystem information might get out of sync If you access the FS from somewhere else, too. (Or you need to reload it all the time, as you stated).

But if you make sure that every Access to the FS is done via your PHP code this could be the best way. When adding new files you can make an entry in the DB. Every access to it also needs to go via your code and update the DB entry If needed.
Reloading the DB every time would no longer be necessary and this could be a good Implementation.

Option 3 is similar to 1. However it can solve the problem with visible filenames and still be simple as you don't need a DB.

Comment: Are you aware that how you suggesting crypting and decrypting to "hide" a filename is a from of security by obscurity -> *"Security Through Obscurity (STO) is the belief that a system of any sort can be secure so long as nobody outside of its implementation group is allowed to find out anything about its internal mechanisms. ... Once the secret gets out, that is the end of your security."*

Comment: It is, if you lets say simply use an md5 hash. But if you use a 'real' encryption it isn't. Add a salt and you are fine. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: *"Or am I missing your point?"* i indeed think you are missing mine point of mine first comment .. As MD5 hash is not encryption.. Also MD5 is not even to be considerd safe anymore nowadays..

Comment: No, that was a misleading example of mine. I was in hurry, sorry. So again: It is an STO if you only use an md5 hash for hiding the filename. If instead, you use a real encryption, with a secure hash function like sha and also add a salt etc. it is not.

Comment: Oh, and thinking about it i came up with another problem. When you are using a plain id in the query you make it possible to easily delete all available files, even If the user might not know them. You could Just use: `delete.php?id=1` and `delete.php?id=2` and so on.

Comment: The main problem is that the safety is as strong as the weakest link, so if the authentication method/layer is leak the whole system after is also simply unsafe..Which i also already commented on the topicstarter question.. As the topicstarter already explained it would be a webapplication where trusted users can login.. This question is far to broad to be answered on also still this would be a "primarily opinion-based" question..

Comment: When you only have trusted users, as you stated before, than an STO is not a critical problem in this Case right? That was the reason why i added the answer that way. I will extend my answer to avoid wring interpretations.

Comment: *"When you only have trusted users, as you stated before, than an STO is not a critical problem in this Case right?"* it is a webapplication, when there is a SQL injection in the login process "everybody" can come in..

Comment: OK. You are right. Let's go back to the beginning of our discussion. Could you please explain how using an id as representation of the files differs from using a (secure) encryption of the filename? Let's assume only filename without any path or subpath is allowed.

Comment: well if the server knows the encryption/hash method and the client does not... It does not matter if the client sends `id=1` or `id=somelongrandomlyencryptedhashfromsomeunknownalgortihm` to delete the file with id 1 right?  Anyhow we are moving way to much offtopic..

Comment: Wow, i finally got it. The problem is that the encryption takes place on client side. Sorry for wasting your time...

Answer (score 0):

Use a PHP Framework like [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), and start to do things right. You're not even using HTML Method DELETE. With your code a POST call to delete.php will delete anything that you set in the URL. With Slim your code will be like that, and you will not go to hell:

```
    <?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->delete('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $id = $request->get('id');
    $path = "/path/to/directory/";
    //$filename = ???;
    //unlink($path . $filename);
    $response->getBody()->write("success");
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

By the way, remember to take a look to [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: Usually I don't want to use Frameworks or third-part code, without understand what I'm doing first. Anyway, I will give it a look. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: So what you want is to use PHP like all those people who have gotten PHP to be in the shit place. You can do things by yourself, but you're going to spend a lot of time, and probably you won't get a code as secure and reliable as a probed and widely used framework. Trust me, the composer way is the nice way.